# How to track changes in a specified folder on c#

Tags: c#

1. I need the following for adding and removing files and folders.
2. I need to watch for changes in files and folders.
3. All actions must be recursively.

How to do it all on c#?

Comment: Any effort so far?

Comment: FileSystemWatcher allows all of this? Give me simple example please

Comment: @Soner Gönül: only got this task :)

Comment: @Basil Google it. There has been no effort shown on this question, just a request for the community to write your code. I suggest researching your task, attempting it and *if* you have difficulties, post a new question containing the code and the relevant question.

Comment: @Robert How I can delete this my question?

Comment: It's right next to share, edit and flag.

Comment: I answered the question but I agree with @Basil you should do a quick search and try few things before asking a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# FileSystemWatcher, How to know file copied completely into the watch folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277991/c-sharp-filesystemwatcher-how-to-know-file-copied-completely-into-the-watch-fol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 FileSystemWatcher
```

Here is a simple code example watching for created file:

```
public void Watcher()
{
    //Create a new FileSystemWatcher.
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    //Set the filter to only catch TXT files.
    watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

    //Subscribe to the Created event.
    //Created Occurs when a file or directory in the specified Path is created.
    //You can change this based on what you are trying to do.
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(YOUR_EVENT_HANDLER);

    //Set the path to you want to monitor
    watcher.Path = @"C:\PATH\";

    //Enable the FileSystemWatcher events.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

Comment: Change newFileSystemWatcher to new FileSystemWatcher